# express-session not saving data

Tags: express, session, mean-stack, express-session

I have a simple MEAN app and I want to implement a simple "home-made" user authentication. My idea is to save the userId in the session when he logs in, and to check if userId exists in the session on each page request (for example, when getting the list of all users).

**Backend - server.js:**

```
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

var MemoryStore = session.MemoryStore;
app.use(
  session({
    name: "app.sid",
    secret: "my_s3cr3t",
    resave: true,
    store: new MemoryStore(),
    saveUninitialized: true
  })
);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

const dbConfig = require("./config/database.config.js");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose
  .connect(dbConfig.url)
  .then(() => {
    // ...
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // ...
    process.exit();
  });

require("./app/routes/user.routes.js")(app);
require("./app/routes/task.routes.js")(app);
require("./app/routes/login.routes.js")(app);

app.listen(3333, () => {
  console.log("Server is listening on port 3333");
});
```

When a user clicks the Login button, a method from the frontend controller is called:

**Frontend - login.controller.js:**

```
vm.login = function() {
    userService.getUserByUsername(vm.username).then(user => {
      if (user.password === vm.password) {
        console.log("Login ok");
        loginService.login(user).then(($window.location.href = "/#!main"));
      } else {
        console.log("Login not ok");
      }
    });
  };
```

**Backend - login.controller.js:**

```
exports.login = (req, res) => {
  req.session.userId = req.body._id;
  req.session.save(function(err) {
    console.log(err); // prints out "undefined", so there's no error
  });
  console.log(req.session);
  res.status(200).send({
    message: "Login ok"
  });
};
```

The frontend LoginController prints out "Login ok" (assuming that I entered correct credentials) and redirects me to the "main" page which uses `main.controller.js`:

In the meantime, the backend login controller prints out the following:

```
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true },
  userId: '5b4746cafe30b423181ad359' }
```

So there is definitely a `userId` in the session content. However, when I get redirected to the `main.html` and the `main.controller.js` gets invoked, it calls:

`loginService.getSession().then(data => console.log(data));`

(I just want to check if the userId is still in the session, and later I will perform some useful actions)

The `getSession()` method in the frontend LoginService only does the `$http` call:

```
function getSession() {
    return $http.get("http://localhost:3333/session").then(
      function(response) {
        return response.data;
      },
      function(error) {
        console.log(error.status);
      }
    );
  }
```

This one calls the method which is defined in the backend LoginController:

```
exports.getSession = (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.session);
  if (req.session.userId) {
    res
      .status(200)
      .send({ message: "Session existing with userId " + req.session.userId });
  } else {
    res.status(404).send({ message: "Session not existing" });
  }
};
```

The frontend call prints the status code 404 in the console, while in the backend I get the following output:

```
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true } }
```

(no `userId` is present...)

One more thing... In a few tutorials I saw that they are using `cookie-parser`. However, when I try to use it, I don't get any data from my database, only the static text is displayed. So I removed it temporarily from `server.js`.

**EDIT:**

I tried adding MongoStore to my app:

```
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")(session);
...
app.use(
  session({
    name: "app.sid",
    secret: "G4m1F1c4T10n_@ppL1c4t10N",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { maxAge: 600000 },
    store: new MongoStore({ url: "mongodb://localhost:27017/myAppDb" })
  })
);
```

...but nothing changed.

How can I get my sessions to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out after talking to several people, sessions are more or less deprecated and the new way of handling these things are the tokens. So I switched to JWT and it's working great.